# Removing or hiding Sitecore navigation items based on cookie value

Tags: cookies, sitecore

I have a popup that asks a user which state they are from, the state is stored in a cookie. I need to be able to hide certain navigation items based on the state that the user is coming from. I set up a "Navigation Exclusion" item in Sitecore for west coast and east coast states which have a treelist of pages to hide for each east or west coast.

My question and confusion comes when I'm trying to figure out where to implement this code so that these navigation items are hidden to the user. I don't have access to the navigation rendering. What is the best practice for implementing a settings item at a global level for Sitecore?

Comment: How is your navigation built up? Is there a check both on each item which should be included in the navigation or a set of items which point to items in your tree? Is the navigation component statically bound in code? What do you mean you do not have access to the rendering, as in you cannot make any code changes to it?

Comment: The navigation is an XSLT rendering based on the items in the content tree, I cannot make any code changes to it because our client has sections of code that are regularly updated by new packages and we try not to change anything that could be overwritten by these packages.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion...

You can create roles (west coast and east coast) and assign these roles on the fly using virtual users
See at: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Security/Faking%20user%20roles/Virtual%20user.aspx
Then it will be just a matter of assigning the right permission to the items for each role.

UPDATE:

I have done something similar on a project I am working today.

1st - Create a role under the extranet domain `"extranet\WestCoast"`

2nd - Create a security preset, go to Assign Security and do the following

- Select the User `extranet\Anonymous` and break its inheritance
- Select the role `extranet\WestCoast`, break inheritance and give Read permission.

  [image]

3rd - Select the Item you want to secure and on the Security Ribbon use the preset "Add West Coast Role", save and check the security->details if the settings are applied.

4rd - Use this method to create and login the virtual user. You can call it in you layout load passing the roles based on the cookie value.

```
public static void CreateVirtualUser(string username, params string[] roles)
{
    var virtualUser = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(username, true);
    
    //clear roles - not sure if really needed
    virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.AddedRoles.Clear();
    virtualUser.Roles.RemoveAll();

    //add the extranet roles
    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        string domainRole = string.Format("extranet\\{0}", role);
        if (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.Exists(domainRole))
        {
            virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.AddedRoles.Add(domainRole);
        }
    }
    Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(virtualUser);
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Wouldn't these users be able to login to Sitecore then?

Comment: I added a update. I tried and the user don`t have access to sitecore because of the lack of roles assign to it.

Comment: This is really great, I like this I'm going to test it out and see if it will fit the bill. Thank you, I definitely wouldn't have thought of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the code for the navigation component, the only thing I can think of is for you to create a new component that executes some client side code(js) that removes the HTML from the nav component for items in your "navigation exclusion" item. It's a hack but it should work until you figure out a better way.

Comment: This is what I'm leaning towards, with the code restrictions it is difficult to find another solution. I don't like that I have to use a hack here but I can't think of any other way.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a rule and setting that rule in presentation definition of the rendering under personalisation?

This way you can simply tick which rendering from the presentation layer to hide.

The rule can simply read from the cookie and hide rendering as the action if it is true.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for?